# Does Backbone work with Mootools?

Tags: dom, backbone.js, mootools

I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience writing a Backbone application with Mootools as it's ajax/dom library instead of jQuery. I know it's possible but is it going to be a headache? Are there any gotchas I need to know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm currently using a modified version of that MooTools adapter that @Dimitar Christoff linked here, which supports events.

I also modified that to use MooTools `agent` instead of `Request`, and after that I realized that I could write my own adapter so I can use all the new MooTools stuff (namely Prime, Agent, Moofx and Elements which comprise MooTools 2.0), that repo is here:
https://github.com/kentaromiura/Marrow

While it's still in alpha and the code is just hacked together to made the tests pass, it's seemingly working now.

I think that every bit of the original adapter has been replicated while other features work thanks to what is implemented into `Elements` and `Slick`.

Though, probably this is not what you meant by "MooTools", so I'll look into branching my repository and copying in all the changes I made to the original adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. Can't wait to see how Marrow turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone **need** JQuery or Zepto... One of this is **required** for both DOM manipulation & Ajax...